# C - While loop runs twice when it shouldn't

Tags: c

Hi I'm making a simple Hangman game in C

I have a while Loop that is suppose to wait for the user to input a character. However, it skips pass that on the 2nd iteration.

```
void startGuessing(char *word){
    char dummyWord[13];
    strcpy(dummyWord, word);

    int dummyWordLength = strlen(dummyWord);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dummyWordLength; i++)
    {
        dummyWord[i] = '_';
    }


    int remaindingChances = 7;
    while(remaindingChances > 0){
        printf("Player 2 has so far guessed: %s\n", dummyWord);
        printf("Player 2, you have %d guesses remaining. Enter your next guess:\n", remaindingChances);

        char guess;
        guess = getchar();

        int wordLength = strlen(word);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
        {
            if(guess == word[i]){
                dummyWord[i] = word[i];
            }
        }

        remaindingChances--;
    }
}
```

The following is the output I'm seeing:

```
Player 2 has so far guessed: ___
Player 2, you have 7 guesses remaining. Enter your next guess:
c
Player 2 has so far guessed: c__
Player 2, you have 6 guesses remaining. Enter your next guess:
Player 2 has so far guessed: c__
Player 2, you have 5 guesses remaining. Enter your next guess:
```

Am i doing something wrong? O.o I can't seem to figure out this issue.

Comment: `getchar` reads every character including the newline you type.

Comment: @WeatherVane How should i fix the issue? Sorry I'm not very sure. I'm very new to C

Comment: I suggest you read a whole line, as a string, using e.g. `fgets`. Then get the first character from the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is probably to consume whitespace by replacing the `guess = getchar()` with something like:

```
int guess;
while( isspace(guess = getchar()) ) { ; }
```

(Note that `getchar` returns an `int`, and you should get in the habit of declaring the variable as an `int`.)

If you want to allow words that contain whitespace, you could use `while( (guess = getchar()) != '\n' )` or similar.  Whatever logic you want to use, you need to handle all the data, including the newlines.  (and be aware of the possibility of `\r\n` on the input)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
scanf(" %c", &guess);
```

for your input.
You can implement further logic to to make sure the input is a letter, but this should fix your current problem